# Django Inclusion tag

Tags: django, шаблоны

Пытаюсь создать включающий тэг, которому передается объект модели `Player` и он отображает информацию о переданном игроке(поля модели)

В директории templatetags(там есть другие включающие тэги, созданные не мной и работающие) в файле `player.py` создаю собственно функцию для тэга и регистрирую:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('gamecore/main_menu/PlayerInfo.html', name='player_info')
def player_info(player):
    return {'player': player}
```

В файл `PlayerInfo.html` кладу простой html:

```
<!--Информация в левом верхнем углу-->
<h2>Player Info</h2>
```

И пытаюсь использовать в другом шаблоне с передачей аргумента `player`, который передается в этот шаблон:

```
{% extends 'gamecore/Header.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Работающий тэг -->
{% load sidemenu %}
<!-- Мой тэг -->
{% load player %}

{% block for_scripts_and_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "css/overview.css" %}'/>
{% endblock %}

<!-- Информация о текущем игроке  -->
{% player_info player %}
```

Но на странице ничего не отображается?

Возможно я забыл что-то важное? Делал все по документации...

Использую `Django 1.11.12`

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion tag вставляет html в заданное место. В данном случае этот тэг стоит между `{% block ... %}` тэгами, соответственно не входит ни в один их них, а так как шаблон, в котором используется тэг наследуется от другого - `{% extends 'gamecore/Header.html' %}`, то тот html, который вставляет мой тэг просто не отображается ни в одном из блоков(он же не в блоке). Проблема решилась перенесением тэга в основной блок шаблона.

Если сказал непонятно, и есть такая же проблема, готов пояснить поподробнее. Хотя ошибка глупая и вряд ли это кому-то поможет. Но вдруг...